# How do I use params in call to mocked method in a "real" method?

Tags: c#, lambda, moq

I'm mocking a method with this signature:

```
public async Task<string> Upsert(Preferences prefs, string id)
```

... and I want to Moq it using a method I've already defined in the testing class. That is, I *don't* want to use a lambda expression.

How do I pass the parameters sent to the mocked method to the "real" method the way I would with a lambda expression?

---

#### Calling a lambda expression (parameters match those sent at call)

That is, if this is how I'd write with a lambda...

```
_mockDataAdapater
    .Setup(x => x.Upsert(It.IsAny<Preferences>(), It.IsAny<string>()))
    .Returns((Preferences p, string id) =>
    {
        return Task.FromResult(id);    
        // see how I can use  ^^^^  the `id` param here?
    });
```

... I get returned the value in the `id` parameter in a call.

```
public async void testMe()
{
    var output  = await _mockDataAdapater.Object.Upsert(new Preferences(), "hello");

    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(output);    // <<< "hello" in this case.
}
```

That's what I want.

#### Calling a "real" function (always "spam")

How do I *not* specify the values of the parameters `p` & `id` on set up and still use this syntax?

```
// This is what I want to use instead of a lambda expression.
private async Task<string> _upsertMock(Preferences prefs, string id)
{
    return await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        return id;
    });
}

//...

public MyClassConstructor()
{
    // Set up mock objects...

    _mockDataAdapater
        .Setup(x => x.Upsert(It.IsAny<Preferences>(), It.IsAny<string>()))
        .Returns(_upsertMock(new Preferences(), "spam")); 
        // Both params are hard coded! ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ 
        // 
        // (Rather, if I don't insert hard-coded params here, I can't
        //  get things to build. How do I hook up to the It.IsAnys?)
}
```

This *always* returns "spam" in the `testMe` call. Bad Moq!

```
public async void testMe()
{
    var output  = await _mockDataAdapater.Object.Upsert(new Preferences(), "hello");

    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(output);    // <<< now always "spam"
}
```

To be clear, I know why I'm always getting `"spam"`. That makes sense. But it stinks.

My question is how to get back to using the params in the "real" method call in this second case?

---

#### This works, but feels wrong

I can [wrap my function in another function](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3i-BzVWQA0Q&t=46)...

```
_mockDataAdapater
    .Setup(x => x.Upsert(It.IsAny<Preferences>(), It.IsAny<string>()))
    .Returns((Preferences p, string id) =>
    {
        return _upsertMock(p, id);
    });
```

Is wrapping the only way I can access `p` and `id`?

Comment: Just pass the method `.Returns(_upsertMock);` provided it matches the delegate of the `Returns` method

Comment: @Nkosi That's what I would've expected, but I get `Error CS1503 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'method group' to 'Task<string>'` when I try to use `.Returns(_upsertMock);` with the code, as written, above. Can you tell what doesn't match? I'm suspicious it's an async edge case, but...

Comment: Did you try my suggestion in the answer provided? I ran it and it work as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried the following proof and it worked as expected

```
[TestClass]
public class MyTestClass {
    public class Preferences {

    }
    public interface IInterface {
        Task<string> Upsert(Preferences prefs, string id);
    }

    public Task<string> _upsertMock(Preferences prefs, string id) {
        return Task.Run(() => {
            return id;
        });
    }

    [Test]
    public async Task MyTestMethod() {

        var mock = new Mock<IInterface>();
        mock
            .Setup(_ => _.Upsert(It.IsAny<Preferences>(), It.IsAny<string>()))
            .Returns((Func<Preferences, string, Task<string>>)_upsertMock);

        var expected = "123";

        var actual = await mock.Object.Upsert(null, expected);

        actual.Should().Be(expected);
    }
}
```

Note the casting of the delegate

```
.Returns((Func<Preferences, string, Task<string>>)_upsertMock);
```

so that the correct `.Returns` overload is used during setup.

Comment: I see lots of `Returns` overloads in [`IReturns.Generated.cs`](https://github.com/moq/moq4/blob/master/src/Moq/Language/IReturns.Generated.cs). Can you tell why it couldn't map the function without the explicit cast? (And I'll admit I don't know why there's a separate `.Generated.cs` version of `IReturns` here with all those overloads, but that's another question.) You've certainly found *how to fix* what was wrong, and, on second look, that error is suggesting as much, but I'll admit I'm still not sure why it couldn't find the right overload on its own.

Comment: @ruffin It was not able to infer the generic arguments from the delegate because there is an actual delegate overload that took presidense when you passed the method delegate

Comment: Did a little more digging. For some reason, the original code `.Returns<Preferences, string>(_upsertMock);` gets routed to `IReturnsResult<TMock> Returns(TResult value);`. Not sure why that is. **A slightly easier/cleaner way** is to use the types in the Results call like this: `.Returns<Preferences, string>(_upsertMock);`, which, as with your cast, calls this overload: `IReturnsResult<TMock> Returns<T1, T2>(Func<T1, T2, TResult> valueFunction);`. I feel like there's likely some method that'd make intentions clearer to the compiler, but I'll go with this cleaner way & call it a day. Thanks!